# What happens when a user modifies their MySite in SharePoint designer on MOSS?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-designer, mysite

One of our users modified their MOSS MySite using SharePoint designer. Now all newly created MySites contain that one user's customizations.

Is this how MOSS is supposed to work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They did not modify thier own MySite, they modified the person.aspx page (ghosting it). This page is used as the template for all subsequent mysite person.aspx pages. Moss does not update any mysites that have already been created when the page changes.

**Update**

As [Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22970/nico) pointed out, I have not been exact with my language. The answer has been updated to reflect that.

They did not modify thier own MySite, they modified the template for all mysites. Moss does not update any mysites that have already been created when the template changes.

Comment: I thought this to be true. What a terrible design.

Comment: I think any way of doing this is going to be a compromise due to the way the MySite.aspx works. The alternatives are that SharePoint edits only the personal site, annoying those who do want to edit the template, or a new button has to be added to SPDesigner to swap between personal and public views.

Comment: I don't think you're correct. When modifying a mysite, other site are not updated. They either modified person.aspx or the mysite template on the filesystem. A standard user cannot moidfy mysite template.

Comment: Good point, though average users don't have SharePoint designer (oh I really hope).